# AWS: Cloudfront and EC2 on single domain

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

Is it possible to host mysite.com/ from ec2 and mysite.com/logo.gif from cloudfront?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you won't be able to make the part of the URL after the domain name influence the [DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) lookup for mysite.com.  However, if you're willing to settle for something like "images.mysite.com/logo.gif", you can easily resolve images.mysite.com to your CloudFront distribution using a [CNAME](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/index.html?CNAMEs.html).

You could also configure the web server on your EC2 instance to redirect or proxy to CloudFront - but then your server is still getting hit every time that resource is loaded, which eliminates most of the benefit to using a CDN in the first place.

Comment: Reverse proxy definitely wouldn't make sense in this case, and adding a redirect may actually make performance worse.

Answer (score 2):

In a way, you can. You would need to use a reverse proxy on your web server at mysite.com.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy

Answer (score 0):

To agree with David (above), you can set up a DNS CNAME for your CloudFront distribution, but the best you could do would be a subdomain of your site. It's a better way to do things anyway, if you follow Yahoo! or Google website performance guidelines.

- developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html
- code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/rules_intro.html